# How to add Jquery Plugins to django

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am learning django and i have a model called `Song` which has a many to many field `singer`. Now In the admin section  I have a simple Multi select field for this field.

Now I would Like to change the Multi Select field suing the [Select2 Plugin](https://select2.github.io).

I have also added a class to singer Field by doing this :

**forms.py**

```
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ['title', 'lyrics', 'singer']
        widgets = {
            'singer': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'multipleSelectBox'}),
        }
```

Now I picked Up the Minified JS and CSS files form the CDN Link provided on their Home Page, and include the JS and CSS to my Page by doing this :

**admin.py**

```
class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        class Media:
            def __init__(self):
                pass

            css = {
                "all": ('css/plugins/select2.min.css', )
            }
            js = ('js/plugins/select2.min.js', 'js/songs.js')

        form = SongForm


admin.site.register(Song, SongAdmin)
```

In **js/songs.js**

```
(function($){
    $(".multipleSelectBox").select2();
})(django.jQuery);
```

When I load this in browser I get the error in console :

> Select2: An instance of jQuery or a jQuery-compatible library was not
>   found. Make sure that you are including jQuery before Select2 on your
>   web page.

However when I check the Page Source I can see the Jquery.js is being loaded before the select2.min.js.

Dont know where i messed Up. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this but this is what i did, In case any one needs help.

Seems like django modifies the Jquery scope and so i decided to use other Jquery file

```
class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        css = {
            "all": ('css/plugins/select2.min.css', )
        }
        js = (
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
            'js/plugins/select2.min.js',
            'js/songs.js'
        )
```